# How do you change the height of a rich:chart bar chart?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, flot

I have a bar chart that is built using rich:chart (richfaces). Everything works fine except that the legend exceeds the height of the bar chart. How do I adjust the overall height of the chart? There is no height attribute or anything that is equivalent to it. Adjusting the height of its div container does not help either.

[image: bar chart]

Comment: http://imgur.com/SHmaczN - image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the height of `div.chart-container`. Use @styleClass to add the class with correct height.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I used to solve my question:

```
.chart-container {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 10px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 10px);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 10px);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 10px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6 0, #fff 10px);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: bold;
}
```